# Podman fails, pulling bigger images on Fedora 32

Tags: linux, containers, fedora, podman

I am facing a weird behavior on my Fedora 32 box.
One thing upfront, I have two boxes running under Fedora 32. One of the boxes works just fine and the other, which is my current work laptop, runs into the issues, I'm going to describe in detail now.

Podman is able to pull images but if they exceed a certain size, I run into a tar-related error

```
❯ podman pull node:12-alpine
Completed short name "node" with unqualified-search registries (origin: /etc/containers/registries.conf)
Trying to pull registry.fedoraproject.org/node:12-alpine...
  manifest unknown: manifest unknown
Trying to pull registry.access.redhat.com/node:12-alpine...
  name unknown: Repo not found
Trying to pull registry.centos.org/node:12-alpine...
  manifest unknown: manifest unknown
Trying to pull docker.io/library/node:12-alpine...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 0a6724ff3fcd skipped: already exists  
Copying blob e21405c347ae done  
Copying blob 80b224d472a8 done  
Copying blob 5fd2bdfdbf4b done  
Copying config 0206ff8a5f done  
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
  Error processing tar file(signal: killed): 
Error: 4 errors occurred while pulling:
 * Error initializing source docker://registry.fedoraproject.org/node:12-alpine: Error reading manifest 12-alpine in registry.fedoraproject.org/node: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
 * Error initializing source docker://registry.access.redhat.com/node:12-alpine: Error reading manifest 12-alpine in registry.access.redhat.com/node: name unknown: Repo not found
 * Error initializing source docker://registry.centos.org/node:12-alpine: Error reading manifest 12-alpine in registry.centos.org/node: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
 * Error committing the finished image: error adding layer with blob "sha256:5fd2bdfdbf4bc383aabf3a03afec47f0e8b5542443e0d6edb74752991651d22a": Error processing tar file(signal: killed):
```

Whereas the following just works as expected:

```
❯ podman pull redis:6-alpine
Completed short name "redis" with unqualified-search registries (origin: /etc/containers/registries.conf)
Trying to pull registry.fedoraproject.org/redis:6-alpine...
  manifest unknown: manifest unknown
Trying to pull registry.access.redhat.com/redis:6-alpine...
  name unknown: Repo not found
Trying to pull registry.centos.org/redis:6-alpine...
  manifest unknown: manifest unknown
Trying to pull docker.io/library/redis:6-alpine...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 054f304e4d13 skipped: already exists  
Copying blob 4c0d98bf9879 skipped: already exists  
Copying blob 6ca68aee953e skipped: already exists  
Copying blob 5d65ae1c666f skipped: already exists  
Copying blob cc1404096495 skipped: already exists  
Copying blob c8b085ca330a [--------------------------------------] 0.0b / 0.0b
Copying config 18e4b21eb3 done  
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
18e4b21eb324530849a8224263413870807d5dfdee5674e6d763be0acc186811
```

Here's my podman info (in case it helps)

```
❯ podman info --debug
host:
  arch: amd64
  buildahVersion: 1.18.0
  cgroupManager: systemd
  cgroupVersion: v2
  conmon:
    package: conmon-2.0.25-1.fc32.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/conmon
    version: 'conmon version 2.0.25, commit: 70f7fbb2f9b93b082ecb9cfe6505c7b557062799'
  cpus: 8
  distribution:
    distribution: fedora
    version: "32"
  eventLogger: journald
  hostname: localhost
  idMappings:
    gidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 1000
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 100000
      size: 65536
    uidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 1000
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 100000
      size: 65536
  kernel: 5.10.12-100.fc32.x86_64
  linkmode: dynamic
  memFree: 5446406144
  memTotal: 33274793984
  ociRuntime:
    name: crun
    package: crun-0.17-1.fc32.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/crun
    version: |-
      crun version 0.17
      commit: 0e9229ae34caaebcb86f1fde18de3acaf18c6d9a
      spec: 1.0.0
      +SYSTEMD +SELINUX +APPARMOR +CAP +SECCOMP +EBPF +CRIU +YAJL
  os: linux
  remoteSocket:
    path: /run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock
  rootless: true
  slirp4netns:
    executable: /usr/bin/slirp4netns
    package: slirp4netns-1.1.8-1.fc32.x86_64
    version: |-
      slirp4netns version 1.1.8
      commit: d361001f495417b880f20329121e3aa431a8f90f
      libslirp: 4.3.1
      SLIRP_CONFIG_VERSION_MAX: 3
      libseccomp: 2.5.0
  swapFree: 8262774784
  swapTotal: 8262774784
  uptime: 27h 20m 18.12s (Approximately 1.12 days)
registries:
  search:
  - registry.fedoraproject.org
  - registry.access.redhat.com
  - registry.centos.org
  - docker.io
store:
  configFile: /home/mvelten/.config/containers/storage.conf
  containerStore:
    number: 0
    paused: 0
    running: 0
    stopped: 0
  graphDriverName: overlay
  graphOptions:
    overlay.mount_program:
      Executable: /usr/bin/fuse-overlayfs
      Package: fuse-overlayfs-1.4.0-1.fc32.x86_64
      Version: |-
        fusermount3 version: 3.9.1
        fuse-overlayfs: version 1.4
        FUSE library version 3.9.1
        using FUSE kernel interface version 7.31
  graphRoot: /home/mvelten/.local/share/containers/storage
  graphStatus:
    Backing Filesystem: extfs
    Native Overlay Diff: "false"
    Supports d_type: "true"
    Using metacopy: "false"
  imageStore:
    number: 2
  runRoot: /run/user/1000/containers
  volumePath: /home/mvelten/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes
version:
  APIVersion: 2.1.0
  Built: 1607438263
  BuiltTime: Tue Dec  8 15:37:43 2020
  GitCommit: ""
  GoVersion: go1.14.10
  OsArch: linux/amd64
  Version: 2.2.1
```

I already excluded volume size issues. A prune and reset of all storage-related directories was also not successful. Re-installing didn't help either.

To me it looks like when a pulled image exceeds a certain size, it's always running into the pointed out tar-related error.

And then, when I run the very same pull request from the other Fedora (32) box, it just works. Super weird and I have no clue, where to look for potential fixes (spent quite some time, crawling the internet for something like that).

Any help or advice would be highly appreciated since I'm fairly blocked right now.

Comment: you have enough space in the disk?

Comment: yes, sorry for not mentioning it above ... I checked all mounted locations and all of them do have enough (>16gb) space

Answer (score 0):

Okay ... question answered by myself ... The actual root cause of my issues is a software named "SentinelOne", which we are supposed to run on our work laptops ... It's proven, that it blocked podman during the pull.

Comment: By any chance did you fixed this error in another way than turning off "SentinelOne" ?

Comment: Hey, unfortunately there was no way to get it running. I had to inform our sec department and they were able to whitelist podman. Since then, everything works smoothly. Sorry that I have no better answer for you.